# Why does bootstrap ignore some of my styles and accept others even when things are in the same class?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angularjs and Bootstrap to make a web application and I'm using Bootstrap's `nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse` classes to set the styles for the navigation bar. I'm trying to change the way the menu options work when they are active.

I've added this to my css file

```
.navbar-nav li.active {
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height:40px;
}
```

The problem is that I only see some of the changes. When a menu option is active the text is now underlined, but the color is still the same color as before and the height is unchanged.

Why does bootstrap use some CSS while ignoring other things when they are in the same class?

Comment: Maybe just specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Note - bootstrap isn't selectively using the CSS - the browser is. See the browser's developer tools to determine the specificity as mentioned above.

Comment: I agree with callmekatootie.  Press F12 on your browser and start inspecting (just select them) the elements tags (<div>, <span>, etc) that you expected to see changed.  Then check the resultant visual attributes and the rules used to determine the resultant attributes.  I am pretty sure you will see the expected setting in the CSS class is being overridden by some other class or a manual style setting.

Comment: @JerryKur There are certain things that are being overridden. I've used F12 to inspect different elements and you are correct in guessing that some things are being overridden by bootstrap. The problem is that I don't know how to fix it. I've been trying lots of things, including what I asked in this question but nothing seems to work.

Comment: j. jerrod.  Yes, bootstrap will override things.  But it is cascading style sheets  so the last definition wins.  Say you the color attribute being set in 3 place, the last definition wins.  Who is last is determined by the last definition of color seen.  So if you hard code it in a style tag on the element (not recommended for production, but a good test) that is the last definition.  Alternatively you could create your own style definition, put it in the file mystyles.css, and ensure that mystyles.css is the last css file loaded.

Comment: Oh, also as Ruslan points out you can use the !important tag at the end of the definition.  This is supposedly never needed in a well constructed CSS hierarchy, but sometime you have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When you rewrite something already defined in your bootstrap css included file or defined somewhere else you have to add !important at the end of thr css rule to make the desired css take priority over the other definitions.
To change the color refer to the lowest element before text, in this case use the selector:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a
```

```css
.navbar-nav li.active {
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height:158px !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```